# Exporting Contacts from a list of Accounts

Tags: data-loader, account, contact

We have a list of 10000 Accounts in CSV format that we are updating through Data Loader. We also want to update all the related Contacts. What would be the best way to do this?

The last time i did something similar i had to write a small bit of code to run through a small section of about 200 records at a time to update it. I would prefer to not do this as timing is important for testing one of our integrations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first idea that came to me, is to add a technical field on account (flag, default = false).

1. Extend your CSV with the new flag, set for all = true
2. Update accounts
3. Extract contacts with condition `where Account.MyFlag__c = true`
4. update contacts
5. Delete flag (since not more useful)